# How to migrate users passwords to Symfony FOSUserBundle table

Tags: symfony, passwords, fosuserbundle

I have an old website which I want to migrate to Symfony2 and use the FOSUserBundle.

My 'old' website's database stores encrypted passwords as follows:

`sha1(\"$salt1$plain_text_password$salt2\")`

However, I've not done this before and am not sure on how to go about doing it. Is my only option to somehow configure FOSUserBundle to use the same encryption as the old website? If so, where would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom password encoder  and  override `BasePasswordEncoder ::isPasswordValid()` add your logic in it

example

```
class CustomPasswordEncoder extends BasePasswordEncoder
{
   public function encodePassword($raw,$salt){
       list($salt1,$salt2) = explode(",",$salt);
       return sha1($salt1.$raw.$salt2); // your logic here
   }
    public function isPasswordValid($encoded,$raw,$salt)
    {
      return $this->comparePasswords(
       $encoded,$this>encodePassword($raw,$salt));
    }
}
```

make this class a service

```
service.yml
services:
    custom-password-encoder:
        class: path\to\CustomPasswordEncoder
```

and add this on your security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: {id: custom-password-encoder}
```

you also need to change `User::getSalt()` to return the two salts separated by comma

example

```
Class User extends BaseUser
{
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return "salt1,salt2";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Snippet for Magento migration password logic.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Utils;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BasePasswordEncoder;

class CustomPasswordEncoder extends BasePasswordEncoder
{
    public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
    {
        $salt2 = base64_encode($salt.uniqid());

        // logic from magento
        return md5($salt2.$raw).":".$salt2;
    }

    public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
    {
        // magento logic
        $hashArr = explode(':', $encoded);
        $hashToValidate = md5($hashArr[1] . $raw);

        return $this->comparePasswords(
           $hashArr[0], // first piece of password
           $hashToValidate // $salt.$password md5 hash
        );
    }
}
```